# Maintain direction of effect of subset in a bridge chart even when it is reversed as part of the larger population

Tags: probability

This is to do with weighted odds. I think this is best to show with an example:

|  | Day 1 |  | Day 2 |  | Bridge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Item** | **Weighting** | **Odds** | **Weighting** | **Odds** |  |
| New | 0 | 0% | 500 | 0.5% | 0.019% |
| Remain | 14000 | 2.11% | 13000 | 2.12% | **-0.024%** |
| Gone | 300 | 3% | 0 | 0% | -0.063% |
| Total | 14300 | 2.13% | 13500 | 2.06% | -0.069% |

So I have the following bridge chart values:

**2.13%** -> +0.019% -> **-0.024%** -> -0.063% -> **2.06%**

The problem I have is that the middle bold number (the weighted difference between the populations [{13000 * 2.12% / 13500} - {14000 * 2.11% / 14300}]) in the bridge is negative, even though the Odds for that subgroup is a positive movement (2.11% -> 2.12%).

What calculation should I be doing, I assume that in order to show that middle group as a positive movement the negative movement of 'Gone' will have to be enhanced. I want to show that from Day 1 to Day 2 it went from 2.13% -> 2.06% but I also want to show that 'Remain' went up in this bridge.

Is this even possible to show in a legitimate way?

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of the word "bridge" on this case? What does it represent and how is it calculated?

Comment: Bridge as in a bridge chart. It bridges the gap from day1 to day 2: 2.13 + 0.02 - 0.02 - 0.04 = 2.06.